# SWT tandem scrollbars in composite

Tags: java, swt, scrollbars, scrolledcomposite, tandem

I'm trying to add a button above the [create two ScrolledComposites that scroll in tandem](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/plain/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet167.java) snippet from [swt snippets](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/)

the problem is that if I put the example code in a different Composite than the shell the example not working

```
import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class tandemWithButton {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new RowLayout());
        Button buttonAbove = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        buttonAbove.setText("Button Above");
        buttonAbove.setSize(40, 30);
        // shell.setContent (buttonAbove);

        Composite comp = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        comp.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        final ScrolledComposite sc1 = new ScrolledComposite(comp, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        Button button1 = new Button(sc1, SWT.PUSH);
        button1.setText("Button 1");
        button1.setSize(400, 300);
        sc1.setContent(button1);

        final ScrolledComposite sc2 = new ScrolledComposite(comp, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        Button button2 = new Button(sc2, SWT.PUSH);
        button2.setText("Button 2");
        button2.setSize(300, 400);
        sc2.setContent(button2);

        final ScrollBar vBar1 = sc1.getVerticalBar();
        final ScrollBar vBar2 = sc2.getVerticalBar();
        final ScrollBar hBar1 = sc1.getHorizontalBar();
        final ScrollBar hBar2 = sc2.getHorizontalBar();
        SelectionListener listener1 = new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                int x = hBar1.getSelection() * (hBar2.getMaximum() - hBar2.getThumb()) / Math.max(1, hBar1.getMaximum() - hBar1.getThumb());
                int y = vBar1.getSelection() * (vBar2.getMaximum() - vBar2.getThumb()) / Math.max(1, vBar1.getMaximum() - vBar1.getThumb());
                sc2.setOrigin(x, y);
            }
        };
        SelectionListener listener2 = new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                int x = hBar2.getSelection() * (hBar1.getMaximum() - hBar1.getThumb()) / Math.max(1, hBar2.getMaximum() - hBar2.getThumb());
                int y = vBar2.getSelection() * (vBar1.getMaximum() - vBar1.getThumb()) / Math.max(1, vBar2.getMaximum() - vBar2.getThumb());
                sc1.setOrigin(x, y);
            }
        };
        vBar1.addSelectionListener(listener1);
        hBar1.addSelectionListener(listener1);
        vBar2.addSelectionListener(listener2);
        hBar2.addSelectionListener(listener2);
        comp.pack();
        comp.setSize(400, 300);

        shell.setSize(400, 300);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

can someone please help me understand what am I doing wrong?
how can I put the tandem scrollbars in a composite and add widgets above / below it.
Thanks in advance,
Yossi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in the `RowLayout` which does not reflect the size of parent component, so the `Composite` container gets that bounds it needs, though no scrollbars are necessary.
Change the line with shell layout to `shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());` and you'll get working demo with the button..

Comment: but the button will take half of the shell space this way, if you use RowData for the items inside RowLayout it will be fixed with small button

Comment: Sure, you have to use just different layout manager. That's what I've tried to pointed out..

Comment: How can I achieve the tandem scrollbars using StyledText ?