# Synchronize Text widgets scroll in SWT

Tags: java, user-interface, text, swt, scrollbar

I'm preparing a custom composite which shows two different text (`StyledText` to be more specific) widgets and one single scrollbar. My intention is to apply the scrolling behaviour in the same terms for both text widgets. Listening for scrollbar selection events is quite easy, but for other events such as moving the caret in the text widget or selection events requires listening for more and more events.

My question is, is there a simpler way of tracking for scrolling within the text widget, or should I listen for all the possble events for keeping the scrolling level synchronized?

Comment: May help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577749/swt-tandem-scrollbars-in-composite

Comment: That solution uses a similar approach than the one I'm testing at this moment. However, text widget allows more interaction than simple canvas, so I'm finally handling more events through listeners.